Creating an rqt_gui_cpp Plugin for RQT Using ROS2 and Qt
I am trying to create a custom rqt plug-in for RQT using C++ and Qt. I have a namespace with a class in my main.cpp. Within the class is the main initPlugin(rqt_gui_cpp) function that is supposed to create an RQT plugin. Within that function are Qt widgets and commands that are meant to display camera feeds and other information.
I am having trouble seeing the plug-in in rqt after I build the ROS2 (galactic) package, which leads me to believe either my CMAKE or plugin.xml file is to blame. Any ideas on how to create this plugin along with tips on setting up the files? I only have the following files: package.xml, plugin.xml, CMAKE, and main.cpp.
